# Tomcat: Remote Address Filter on $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm trying to apply a **Remote Address Filter** to a Tomcat 7.0.70 instance as described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_Address_Filter)

The filter works if applied to the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file but it doesn't on the global `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`

Is there anything different I have to do to apply the filter to the global `conf/web.xml`?

- **Tomcat**: 7.0.70
- **OS**: Ubuntu Xenial x64
- **Java**: Oracle JDK 7u79-b15

Remote address filter:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>allow</param-name>
    <param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Link to the `conf/web.xml`: https://nopaste.me/view/30a08f56

Comment: Do you mean you've changed web.xml in your project files? The same time you want these changes for Tomcat server instance on your PC/Server?

Comment: If I apply the filter to the web.xml inside my app (WEB-INF/web.xml) the filter works. If the filter is applied to the web.xml of the tomcat instance (conf/web.xml) the same filter doesn't work

Comment: What if you make changes to Tomcat's `web.xml`? It can be find somwhere there: `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\conf\web.xml`
For sure the path depends on where exactly you've installed the instance of Tomcat.

Comment: that's the issue. The remote address filter applied to that file (`C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\con‌​f\web.xml` in your case) doesn't work. The `conf/web.xml` file itself is not ignored cause if I put invalid XML there Tomcat notices it when starting

Comment: check the instance. it is possible that you have more than one Tomcat instances on one PC and you apply changes to the wrong one.

Comment: Instance is the right one (there's only that one)

Comment: @SergeyLotvin   Can you help to check this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67597085/tomcat-remote-address-filter-is-not-working-tomcat-9-0-x