# Tomcat Remote Address Filter is not working - Tomcat 9.0.X

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters, tomcat9

I'm trying to restrict the some of my application endpoints for public internet. For this I tried tomcat's Remote Address Filter. I added the filter to my application's web.xml `(D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.22\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF)`. but it does not effect at all. I tried both `<param-name>allow</param-name>  <param-name>deny</param-name>` and specific IP addresses of my team member, but still it is we all can access.  Each time of this change, I've restarted the tomcat.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>deny</param-name> <!-- Tried to block my team mate's IP -->
      <param-value>10\.142\.16\.1</param-value>  <!-- My team mates IP address -->

      <!-- param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value -->

    </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Remote Address Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/myApp/context/* </url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Also I tried as in [documentation](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-configure-Tomcat-to-accept-only-localhost-access-for-the-Manager-Application)  `<param-value>127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1</param-value>` but still my team mate and myself can access the pages without any problem.

My environment details>>

```
I've used a standalone Tomcat. Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
Running with Spring Boot v2.1.3.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.5.RELEASE
```

Where could be the problem?  Is there a way to find whether the `web.xml` changes are really reflecting?

Comment: The URL pattern you are using probably shouldn't contain `/myApp`: it is a **relative** path to your application's context path. Try `/*`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz     Here is my URL need to block. `http://localhost:8080/myApp/actuator/health`  Basically I don't want outsiders to see this page.
So, How should I update?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I tried /actuator/* still doesn't work

Comment: you coud use spring security hasIpAddress for this. try https://stackoverflow.com/a/29274970/7887883

Comment: @PavanKumarTS   Hi Pavan, I don't like to implement Spring security only for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. The problem was with the url-pattern. We shouldn't add the application context to the url-pattern.

Now this works with below settings.

```
<url-pattern>/actuator/health </url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add restrictions in application/META-INF/context.xml. this would result in 403 for entire application. you could see the implementation in webapps\manager\META-INF of your tomcat.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" />
</Context>
```